# Codeigniter URL shortening or routing Failed

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-shortener

I am trying to shorten the url

```
https://www.example.com/Flight_booking/search?flight%5Bjourneytype%5D=1&flight%5Bflyingfrom%5D%5B%5D=BLR&flight%5Bflyingto%5D%5B%5D=DEL&flight%5Bdepartingon%5D%5B%5D=31%2F07%2F2017&flight%5Badults%5D=1&flight%5Bchildren%5D=0&flight%5Binfant%5D=0&flight%5BFlightCabinClass%5D=2&seo=bangalore-delhi-flight
```

to

```
mywebsiteurl/fly-to-a-beautiful-destination
```

checked many examples and tried(both .htaccess url rewriting and and codeigniter routes), but no luck. Does any one have any solution for the same?
Tried:

## Specify search friendly URLs

```
RewriteRule ^a-beautiful-url$ /Flight_booking/search?flight%5Bjourneytype%5D=1&flight%5Bflyingfrom%5D%5B%5D=BLR&flight%5Bflyingto%5D%5B%5D=DEL&flight%5Bdepartingon%5D%5B%5D=31%2F07%2F2017&flight%5Badults%5D=1&flight%5Bchildren%5D=0&flight%5Binfant%5D=0&flight%5BFlightCabinClass%5D=2&seo=bangalore-delhi-flight [L]
```

Also in codeigniter routes tried:

```
$routes['a-beautiful-url'] = 'Flight_booking/search?flight%5Bjourneytype%5D=1&flight%5Bflyingfrom%5D%5B%5D=BLR&flight%5Bflyingto%5D%5B%5D=DEL&flight%5Bdepartingon%5D%5B%5D=31%2F07%2F2017&flight%5Badults%5D=1&flight%5Bchildren%5D=0&flight%5Binfant%5D=0&flight%5BFlightCabinClass%5D=2&seo=bangalore-delhi-flight';
```

Comment: And the Long URL works within CodeIgniter?

Comment: yes, it does work

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your route as "a-beautiful-url", that's what it's going to be looking for. If you want it to go to "fly-to-a-beautiful-destination", that's what needs to be specified in the routing.

Also, routing is for the controller and a parameter. So the route would look something like

```
$route['fly-to-a-beautiful-destination/search/(:any)'] = 'flight_booking/search/$1';
```

For SEO, CI discourages the use of the URI string. If you must use it, you'll have to figure out how to parse that.